# Assignment operator += usage with earlier declared vs declared variable?

Tags: c, assignment-operator

I am new to C and got a little confused. I have code where I am using `+=` operator with a variable when declared but it is giving me an error for this operator, but working fine when used inversely i.e. `=+`. Please explain why?

Here is the code:

```c
  int i = 0;
  int g = 99;
  do
  {
    int  f += i;   //Here += is throwing error and =+ is working fine why?
    printf("%-6s = %d ","This is",f);
    i++;
  } while(i<10);
```

```
Error as 
ff.c:16:11: error: invalid '+=' at end of declaration; did you mean '='?
    int f += i;
          ^~
          =
1 error generated.
```

It's working this way:

```
  int i = 0;
  int g = 99;
  do
  {
    int  f =+ i;   //Here += is `your text throwing error and =+ is working fine why?
    printf("%-6s = %d ","This is",f);
    i++;
  } while(i<10);
```

Comment: Which error is generated?

Comment: `+=` is not the same as `=+`.

Comment: In ancient C history, the operators actually were `=+` and `=-` initially. However, when writing this as `f=-i` they didn't know if it was meant to be `f =- i` or `f = -i`.  So the assignment was changed to `+=` and `-=` (over 50 years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition

```
int f =+ 1;
```

is really the same as

```
int f = +1;
```

That is, you're initializing `f` with the value `+1`.

When initializing a variable on definition, you can only initialize it, not modify it.

Comment: So this
 int f = +1;

means that f is being assigned value of 1 and nothing else right?

Comment: yes. same as `>=` is not the same as `=>`

Answer (score 1):

`+=` is a special operator in `C` and it is something completely different that `=+`.

`f += x` adds `x` to `f` and stores it in `f`. It is the same as:
`f = f + x;`

When you declare `f` you can't add anything to it as it does not exist at this point - thus error.

`f=+1` assigns `f` with `1` as `+1 == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The operation

```
x += i;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x + i;
```

So x should initially have a value before using the += operator and you can't use the += operator in the definition of a variable.